# Display output of the exec

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

is there a way to display output from the select statament as below on this stored procedure? Kindly advise . Thanks you

```
SET @sSQL = 'SELECT CHDR.CHDRNUM, ZTRN.CCDATE, CHDR.CRDATE, CLNT.CLNTNUM, CLNT.SURNAME, CLNT.GIVNAME,
            CLNT.SECUITYNO, ZCLN.EMAIL, CLAM.CLAIM, CLAM.CLMDSC, CLAM.PAID from ((((MPIDTA.ZTRNPF AS ZTRN 
            LEFT JOIN MPIDTA.CHDRPF AS CHDR ON ZTRN.RLDGACCT = CHDR.CHDRNUM AND ZTRN.EFFDATE = CHDR.CURRFROM)
            LEFT JOIN MPIDTA.CLNTPF AS CLNT ON CHDR.COWNNUM = CLNT.CLNTNUM)
            LEFT JOIN MPIDTA.ZCLNPF AS ZCLN ON CLNT.CLNTNUM = ZCLN.CLNTNUM)
            LEFT JOIN MPIDTA.CLAMPF AS CLAM ON CHDR.CHDRNUM = CLAM.CHDRNUM)
            where (ZTRN.BATCPFX = ''BA'' AND ZTRN.BATCCOY = ''1''
            AND ZTRN.CNTTYPE = ''PTB'' AND ZTRN.TRANDATE >= ''20150101'' 
            AND (ZTRN.EXPIRY_DATE BETWEEN ' + @FirstDateOfNextMth + ' AND ' + @LastDateOfNextMth + '))
            AND (CHDR.MPLNUM = '''' AND CHDR.CHDRPFX = ''CH''
            AND CHDR.CHDRCOY = ''1'' AND CHDR.VALIDFLAG = ''1'')
            AND (CLAM.DATOCC >= ZTRN.CCDATE AND CLAM.DATOCC <= CHDR.CRDATE)'

SET @sExe = 'Insert into dbo.TPA_Client_Claim_Info Select * FROM OPENQUERY(AS400, ''' + REPLACE(@sSQL, '''', '''''') + ''')'


exec (@sExe)
```

Comment: Add an OUTPUT clause between the INSERT INTO and the SELECT of the final insertion. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: You mean you want to see the data you've inserted into your table or what the DB tells you about the success of your query?

Comment: ya.. i want to see the data that i inserted . thanks  you 
kindly advise

Comment: Just simply SELECT @sSQL if I understood your question

Comment: hmm its not working .. displaying nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @sSQL = 'SELECT CHDR.CHDRNUM, ZTRN.CCDATE, CHDR.CRDATE, CLNT.CLNTNUM, CLNT.SURNAME, CLNT.GIVNAME,
            CLNT.SECUITYNO, ZCLN.EMAIL, CLAM.CLAIM, CLAM.CLMDSC, CLAM.PAID from ((((MPIDTA.ZTRNPF AS ZTRN 
            LEFT JOIN MPIDTA.CHDRPF AS CHDR ON ZTRN.RLDGACCT = CHDR.CHDRNUM AND ZTRN.EFFDATE = CHDR.CURRFROM)
            LEFT JOIN MPIDTA.CLNTPF AS CLNT ON CHDR.COWNNUM = CLNT.CLNTNUM)
            LEFT JOIN MPIDTA.ZCLNPF AS ZCLN ON CLNT.CLNTNUM = ZCLN.CLNTNUM)
            LEFT JOIN MPIDTA.CLAMPF AS CLAM ON CHDR.CHDRNUM = CLAM.CHDRNUM)
            where (ZTRN.BATCPFX = ''BA'' AND ZTRN.BATCCOY = ''1''
            AND ZTRN.CNTTYPE = ''PTB'' AND ZTRN.TRANDATE >= ''20150101'' 
            AND (ZTRN.EXPIRY_DATE BETWEEN ' + @FirstDateOfNextMth + ' AND ' + @LastDateOfNextMth + '))
            AND (CHDR.MPLNUM = '''' AND CHDR.CHDRPFX = ''CH''
            AND CHDR.CHDRCOY = ''1'' AND CHDR.VALIDFLAG = ''1'')
            AND (CLAM.DATOCC >= ZTRN.CCDATE AND CLAM.DATOCC <= CHDR.CRDATE)'

SET @sExe = 'Insert into dbo.TPA_Client_Claim_Info Select * FROM OPENQUERY(AS400, ''' + REPLACE(@sSQL, '''', '''''') + ''')'

SET @sExe = @sExe + ' SELECT * FROM dbo.TPA_Client_Claim_Info'

exec (@sExe)  -- OR EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sExe
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have data inserted in table? Just give **SELECT * FROM dbo.TPA_Client_Claim_Info** after **exec (@sExe)** and check whether data is coming. @Damon Ng

Comment: Is insertion going successfully? @Damon Ng

Comment: indeed i run and it successfully but the output nothing

Comment: Can you just give **SELECT * FROM dbo.TPA_Client_Claim_Info** and check and tell me whether data is there in the table? @Damon Ng

Comment: the data not there sarath

Comment: That means the insertion is not successful. You might have some problem with the code you have provided in the question. Please execute the query in your question and make sure insertion is happening properly and reply me. I can surely help you :) @Damon Ng

Comment: @SarathAvanavu This will return all rows from table and not just newly inserted.

Comment: Do you actually require **Dynamic Sql** here? Because, the first query in ur question will even without **Dynamic Sql**. @Damon Ng